# get a value with a jquery for loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, for-loop

I have several item in a databse, I'm displaying a link with in the href the id of each item.

So I want to get the id from a href which is in a PHP while loop. So I did a for loop to do it but it seems to only get the first href attr.

```
for (var i = 0; i < check; i++) 
{
   var id = $(".id").attr('href');
   console.log(id);
}
```

`Check` is equal to the number of columns in the database depends of a special id. In this case check = 3

The link is: `echo '<a id="dislike" class="btn-primary btn pull-right id" href="'.$items['id'].'">Dislike</a>';`

Any idea of why it doesn't work ?

I got them all!

But how can I make them go out of the function ?

```
function checkingfetchresult(userid){

    $.post("ajax/checkingfetchresult.php", { userid: userid },
            function(check){
            $(".id").each(function(){
                var id = $(this).attr('href');
            });

    });

}
```

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to do here.

Could you update with a little more code, and what you've gotten back from the code, and what you would expect back?  It's hard to help without that info.

Comment: I have an id in the link href, but this id is different depending the link (it comes from the database). So I trying to get this id, but because I have several id, I'm trying to get them all and not only the first one

Comment: oh... so `$('.id')` selects all elements with that class.  you need to do `$('.id').each(function(){...` to loop through all the `id` class elements.

Comment: if id of all the anchor elements(<a>) is same, you will only get the 1st ones href attr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting the same elements on each iteration and then getting the attribute of the first element in the set. Instead of looping like that, you should use [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$(".id").each(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('href');
   console.log(id);
});
```

Comment: Just as a point: while we're cleaning up this code, it's a bad idea to create a new variable on every loop, you should probably move the `var` statement above the `each` in this solution. +1, since this is correct, I think, and the issue wasn't yours to begin with :)

Comment: @rockerest How is it a bad idea? If I move it outside the function it will be unnecessarily exposed to an outer scope.

Comment: I was making an assumption that the outer scope NEEDS access to the ID, since simply `console.log`ing it probably isn't where it's going to be used. It's a bad idea because that variable will be re-initialized with every loop, creating a lot of unnecessary overhead when the count of `$(".id")` gets to be large.

Comment: It's working! If I move the var statement above, I have to do it like this : var id and I have to return id in the function ?

Comment: @TheJailbreakBay first you should determine if you SHOULD move the var statement above. Scoping is a very important part of Javascript.  If you do decide to move it above, the inner anonymous function will already have access to it.  You have to also remember that your function will return the id each time, so if you want access to every one, you'll need to make IDs an array and push to it instead of simply assigning the value.  I'll leave Paulpro's answer alone now, but good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the first element every time, and logging its `href`. You can't expect a loop to behave differently if it's doing the same thing every time?

If you want to get all the `href` attributes for all the `.id` elements, use `map`:

```
$('.id').map(function () { return $(this).attr("href") });
```

It will return an array, where each element is the `href` of the corresponding `.id` element.

Comment: With this, I'm getting that in the console: Object["59", "59", "57", "57", "56", "56"]. Why ?

Comment: Because it's returning an array, where each element is the `href` of the corresponding element.

Comment: the method of paulpro seems to be better to me but I can't make the ids leave the function!

Answer (score 0):

`$(".id")` returns an array-like object, containing all of the matching elements. what you actually want to do is this:

```
var idArray = $(".id");
for (var i = 0; i < check; i++) {
    var id = $(idArray[i]).attr('href');
    console.log(id);
}
```